# Ember.JS Bind to time?

Tags: ember.js

Sorry if this is worded incorrectly, it's hard to explain. Basically I have a list of items that have a specified date next to them. If they are more than 30 minutes old, then they go red. Works perfectly, but it's not in real time. It needs to be refreshed to see the item go red.

```
{{#each callback in App.callbackController}}
    <tr>
        <td align="center" {{bindAttr style="callback.urgent"}}>{{callback.formatted_time}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}

App.Callback = Ember.Object.extend({
    date_time: null,
    urgent: function()
    {
        current_time  = new Date().getTime();
        callback_time = new Date(this.get('date_time')).getTime();

        if(((callback_time - current_time) / 1000 / 60 * -1) > 30)
        {
            return 'color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; background: #'+Helpers.colours.red;
        } else {
            return 'color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; background: #'+Helpers.colours.green;
        }
    }.property('date_time')
});
```

Is there anyway to keep refreshing the urgent value?

Answer (score 1):

Richard Livsey wrote [a wonderful blog post](http://livsey.org/blog/2013/02/20/tick-tock/) that basically adds an app-wide Clock model which is hooked into all controllers via injections. Your computed properties can then bind to the clock properties and be "woken up" at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Your computed property is only looking at the "date_time" property, which in your example looks like it is the time the item was created.

You should probably add a "date_time_now" property somewhere in your app (where it makes sense) and add that to your computed property.  Not sure if ember has a built in "now" property, but that shouldn't be too hard to set up yourself using setTimeout().

**Edit:**

Reread my answer and realized I didn't explain it as well as I could have.  Since your computed property only looks at date_time (which never changes) it will be evaluated once and cached after that since computed properties are cached by default.  Adding the date_time_now property and updating that will force a re-computation every time date_time_now is changed.